# ¿Como mandar variable php desde html a javascript sin onclick?

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Tengo el siguiente problema, quiero eliminar un registro y estoy mandando el id a JavaScript primero, el código me funciona bien pero no me gusta trabajar con onclick, me gusta trabajar mas con addEvenlistener, quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de pasar el id y trabajar con addEvenlistener, Adjunto el código actual que tengo:

```html
<button class="btnEliminar" onclick="eliminar(<?php echo $fila['id']?>)" >Eliminar</button>
```

Ese es el código actual que tengo con onclick, quisiera saber si se puede hacer de la manera que les dije, con addEvenlistener.

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar un attributo "data-id" y agregar el evento a todos los botones con clase `btnEliminar` que posean `data-id`

en el php

```php
<button class="btnEliminar" data-id="<?php echo $fila['id']?>" >Eliminar</button>
```

en el javascript

```js
const eliminar = function(elID) {
  console.log("borrando ID:" + elID)
}
const botonesEliminar = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-id].btnEliminar');

let n = botonesEliminar.length
while (n--) {
  botonesEliminar[n].addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
    eliminar(ev.target.getAttribute('data-id'))
  })
}
```

```html
<pre>
&lt;button class="btnEliminar" data-id="&lt;?php echo $fila['id']?&gt;" &gt;Eliminar&lt;/button&gt;
</pre>
<button class="btnEliminar" data-id="20">Eliminar</button><br/>
<button class="btnEliminar" data-id="315">Eliminar</button><br/>
<button class="btnEliminar" data-id="422">Eliminar</button><br/>
<button class="btnEliminar">Yo no tengo ID</button><br/>
<button class="btnEditar" data-id="522">Yo tengo ID pero no la clase</button><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te doy una idea de como podrías capturar el id, luego dentro de el ya es cuestión de mandar la consulta para eliminarla.

Use `getElementsByClassName`, por la clase que tienes, pero si deseas puedes usar un id y `getElementById`

```js
var btnEliminar = document.getElementsByClassName('btnEliminar');
btnEliminar[0].addEventListener("click", eliminarId);
function eliminarId(){
  var idData = btnEliminar[0].getAttribute('id-data');
  alert(idData);
}
```

```html
<button class="btnEliminar" id-data="<?php echo $fila['id']?>" >Eliminar</button>
```